# Is it possible to parametrize colors in the Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, color

Let's say I create a set of pictures with common color scheme. Is it possible to parametrize most of colors and after pictures creation change common colors? There is some instruments to do similar things like CSS selectors, clones an so on. But if I need two rects, one rect with *dark_color* border and *light_color* fill and second rect with *light_color* border and *dark_color* fill, what shall I do to parametrize this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with CSS.

You could create two CSS classes, one for light stroke and dark fill, and another for dark stroke light fill.  You can use *Extensions > Stylesheet > Merge Styles into CSS* to create the classes from a selection.

Then you can select one of the objects and change the colours in the Selectors and CSS panel.

An example

[image]

Here's [the Inkscape SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/p2C.svg) if you want to play with it.

Another method is to use *Extensions > Colour > Replace Colour*, which should replace all instances of a particular colour regardless of whether it's a stroke or fill. You need to select all the objects to include in the replacement before running the extension.

An example

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your method in your example only changes fills but not borders at once. I'd like to can change at once all red elements (fills, borders curves, text e.t.c.) to blue.

Comment: @Arseniy There's also a replace colour extension you might find useful for your particular use case. I've added it to the answer.